# Magic Chef wall oven, no heat but clock works

Tags: oven, built-ins

I have a Magic Chef MCSWOE24S, a current-model 24" wall oven.
It was working fine for months after installing it. Then we had trouble with our main electrical panel -- one of the poles was burning out due to arcing and became intermittent. One morning I woke up to find the oven clock flicking on and off a few times per second, along with an electrical sound that didn't sound good. So I turned the oven's breaker off in the electrical panel.

After the panel was repaired, the oven's clock works fine but we get no heat from either heating element, and the internal oven light does not go on.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting?

Comment: What was done to repair the panel?  Also, what make and model was/is said panel?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, the panel and all the breakers were replaced, by a local professional electrician with decades of experience and recommended by people in the neighborhood. The original was a GE installed when the house was built in 1963. The new panel is a "Square D" brand. Both are 100 Amp, which was state of the art in 1963 and plenty for our needs.

Comment: Typically an oven will be connected with two hots, neutral and ground. You should get (nominally) 120V between each hot & neutral and 240V between the hots. Also typically, the light, control panel and everything else *except* the heating element is on one part of the circuit (120V) so it seems odd that the clock would work but not the light. But first step is to check incoming voltage on all the wires.

Comment: @manassehkatz, thanks, but this 1963 house has not been rewired with modern 4-wire wiring. Even the electric dryer outlet is the old 3-wire type. The electric box behind the oven where it is connected has 3 wires. I'll check for voltage there tomorrow and let you know what I find.